# Reference Request: Sum of squares in odd characteristic fields

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know the reference for the following result:

> Let $F$ be a field of odd characteristic, then each element can be written as a finite sum of squares in $F$.

I only know the finite case, which can be done by easy group theory. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in F$. Then $$\alpha = \frac12\left((\alpha+1)^2-\alpha^2-1\right)$$
shows that $\alpha$ is a finite sum of squares -- once you notice that all elements of the prime field $\Bbb F_p$ (in particular, $\frac12$ and $-1$) are sums of squares and that  the product of two sums of squares is a sum of squares.